# Creating the straight line feature class representing the shortest path between two features using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

I have a feature class containing the district boundaries for India and a feature class of one of India's national highways. For each district, I calculated the straight line distance to the nearest highway segment using the Near tool (which calculates the distance between the highway to the nearest boundary of a given district).

How can I create the feature class representing the straight line distance created by the Near tool?

I am using ArcMap version 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [help section for Near tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm):

> To visualize the FROM_X, FROM_Y, NEAR_X, and NEAR_Y locations, the
>   output table can be used as input to the Make XY Event Layer or XY To
>   Line tools.

[Make XY Event Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-xy-event-layer.htm):

> Creates a new point feature layer based on x- and y-coordinates
>   defined in a source table. If the source table contains z-coordinates
>   (elevation values), that field can also be specified in the creation
>   of the event layer. The layer created by this tool is temporary.

[XY To Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-to-line.htm):

> Creates a new feature class containing geodetic line features
>   constructed based on the values in a start x-coordinate field, start
>   y-coordinate field, end x-coordinate field, and end y-coordinate field
>   of a table.

Comment: You are a life saver---I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot generate the FROM_X and FROM_Y fields even after setting the location option to True. It only yields the NEAR_X and NEAR_Y fields. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Figured it out. To get the FROM_X and FROM_Y fields, use the Generate Near Table tool, not the Near tool.